# EasyUi datagrid in Asp?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datagrid

Hi everyone I am very new to asp.I want to create data grid for binding data coming from a webservice written in aspx.

I am impressed with jquery easyui. Nut the problem is all the demos are explained with php.

Has anyone done using asp?
The grid is expecting  data in the form

```
{"total":28,"rows":[{"productid":"1","attr":{"size":"10dc","color":"red&yellow"},
                    {"productid":"2","attr":{"size":"102dc","color":"green&null"}
```

How can i Create such a JSON object in  asp?

Comment: to be sure.... asp.net or asp-classic?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to insert an asp gridview into the layout directly. This way we can deal with all of the data exchange using asp and c#. I think that is a better option. The formatting options of the datagrid resulted from using the autoformat options.

In this case I inserted into an accordion in the west pane:

```
<div data-options="region:'west',split:true" title="West" style="width:100px;">
            <div class="easyui-accordion" data-options="fit:true,border:false">
                <div title="Title1" style="padding:10px;">
                    content1
                </div>
                <div title="Title2" data-options="selected:true" style="padding:10px;">
                <form id="form1" runat="server">
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:news_devConnectionString %>' ProviderName='<%$ ConnectionStrings:news_devConnectionString.ProviderName %>' SelectCommand="SELECT contentID, title, siteDatetime, mp3path FROM news_dev.content;"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </form>
                </div>
                <div title="Title3" style="padding:10px">
                    content3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Just testing to see if I could get it in there, obviously needs formatting.

[image]